# Is there a way to see more physics setting for an object?

Tags: physics

I was following a tutorial oh how to make a basic water simulation then I got to the part where I enable the domain's mesh and couldn't find the "mesh" checkbox anywhere. I seem to be missing a few other settings in the physics tab. Is there some advanced settings or something? [image: my physics tab]

[image: what it should look like]

Comment: In your second screenshot the mesh checkbox is there, in blue, already activated. What's the problem?

Comment: so sorry, the second screenshot is what it should look like ( I was watching a tutorial)

Comment: It's under the Liquid subsection, just click the arrow and all will be revealed

Comment: Oh my goodness thank you so much somehow that just passed my mind

Answer (score 0):

Click the little button near the Liquid

[image]